# How to set a specific Domain controller for a user or client machine to logon-authenticate with?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, domain-controller

How to set a specific Domain controller for a user or client machine to logon-authenticate with using the GPO (Group Policy Object) or Registry. I am looking to setup a Specific Domain Controller for 2 classrooms. The classrooms have about 14 people in each room. the DC will also be a "file junction" point. The files will temporarily be stored on the DC for use and then as Night Synced to the Main DC for files.

My plan is to have 1 DC for the 2 Classes. The Classes are Graphics and CADD. All students have their own Accounts that are only saving documents-files to the Local Machine or the Network Drive. Graphics Has MACs and CADD has Windows Machines. The Files will sync with the server in the List to save network utilization....

Any ideas or anything I'm Missing?

Comment: Why not segment them onto their own subnet with one DC on the same subnet?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You are confusing DCs and file servers.

Comment: how is your file saving/syncing plan related to DC? They are two different things.

Comment: The Storage Permission and Storage controlled and managed by the AC D&S. The The reason why want I want place a domain controllers for a designated location is because we  have a lot of authentication Over the network bit not only for the wired in desktops, the laptop cards and Mac book carts along with authentication and permissions of certain strage shares to that specific machine or for that specific user. The storage shares are for the Class shares, Office Shares and user shares, etc.

Comment: I do believe that this Idea is a little extra. The server is not needed. It was only an idea so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what this sounds like to me - ignore freely if my guess is off base.

You've got a classroom site that's geographically remote from your primary network - WAN scenario. You want to give that site an experience that's equal in quality to what they'd experience if they were sitting in the main site.

In AD terms, what you're looking at is a distinct Site. If properly set up, not only will your clients prefer their local DC for login, but (if using DFS) the servers will sync files during low traffic hours - all configured from within AD management tools.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782048(v=ws.10).aspx

It's possible that your login times from the classroom to the main site are perfectly acceptable, in which case you can save the cost of a remote DC and just set up a file server.  Hope that helps!

Comment: What Kara says is I think what you need. PCs will speak to their local DC automatically. They find their DC through being in the same site. You need to use the AD sites and services tool to create 2 sites and link each one to a subnet. You can then promote your second server to a DC. Once promoted make sure in AD sites and services that each  server appears in the correct site. Once this is the case the workstations will just work. Once you have a single domain you can  create users and shares which are accessible in both offices.